# deploy angular/Nodejs Application in heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have separte angular folder and a seperate Nodejs folder for the application.
I want to deploy it in heroku but apparently ondly a nodejs app can be deployed. Is there a solution to deploy my angular/nodejs app?

Otherwise does anyone have an idea on how to combine the angular project folder inside the nodejs project folder ?

Comment: You could use [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) to make use of server side rendering?

Comment: What does the Node app currently look like –– do you use Express, Koa, internal Node HTTP server...? Typically you would just serve the static assets when someone requests a non-API route (e.g. anything other than /api/*). Also, you are not limited to Node.js at Heroku, they support many languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve your angular app as a static content on your node js app.
This depend how your node app is built, for example with express you can just put the files in the public directory.